# How move object with collision (without physics) Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 3d cube which have 3d box collider.

I want to write jump system for cube with collision, but without physics (without gravity, without rotation, etc) (Like 3d platformer)

Comment: I think you can add a `Collider` without a Rigidbody, then you can tick the `isTrigger` box and do (things) in `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit`.

Comment: But how do you imagine jumping without gravity? Anyway, you can program movement by using `transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime)`

Comment: @Kokodoko If use transform.Translate, gameobject can pass through another object

Comment: @Chuck the method is questionable, but in theory I can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [Physics.OverlapBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html) API to check for collisions before committing to move your object.

Your code will look something like this:

```csharp
Vector3 nextPosition = transform.position;
/*
  You do your normal movement code, but apply 
  it to nextPosition instead of transform.position
*/
Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapBox(nextPosition, transform.localScale/2);
if(hitColliders.Length == 0){
  transform.position = nextPosition;
}
```

Note that the object itself shouldn't have a collider, otherwise it will detect itself. You also shouldn't move in big steps as this method doesn't take colliders on the path into account.

Comment: Thanks!

By the way, what if I suddenly have a mesh instead of a cube?

Comment: @Redis there are overlap functions for spheres and capsules, but not for custom meshes. Polygonal meshes slow down physics a lot, which is probably why they didn't include them. If you need a closer approximation than theses primitives you should "box out" the shape.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great way of doing this. You will still need physics.

### The Steps

- Have a rigidbody on your player.
- There should be a dropdown menu called spmethiing like "constraints". Find it.
- Then Set all rotation constraints in this menu to true.

However, I don't understand why you wouldn't want gravity. Don't all platformers have gravity? (There must be some force to pull your player down when they jump). Anyways, if you don't want gravity, then you must **uncheck Use Gravity variable**.

**Notes: **

- To control your player, you must use AddForce(). If you have any questions about adding force, let me know in the comments.

:) Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to use AddForce() to move, you can also use other methods

Comment: @Thien true, but I believe using transform will cause less realistic results and collider bugs. Or were you referring to something else?

Comment: Indeed other methods might cause collision bugs (there are also ways to overcome this problem) but I don't think AddForce() is the one size fit all for every situation.